# How do I echo html tags in PHP Variable?

Tags: php, html, string

Say, `$var = "Hello<br>How are <strong>you</strong>";`

I want `echo $var` to display the assigned string `Hello<br>How are <strong>you</strong>` as it is not the
parsed html code.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to strip the tags? Then use `echo strip_tags($var);`.

Comment: Ah, you want the HTML not parsed by the browser, then use `echo htmlentities($var);`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display HTML snippets in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-snippets-in-html)

Comment: @MarkusZeller htmlentities answers the question.Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using htmlentities in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209237/using-htmlentities-in-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML tags will automatically parsed by the browser. To see the pure HTML source anyways, the tags needs to be encoded, especially the angle brackets.

There is a dedicated PHP function available for that called [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities).

```
$var = "Hello<br>How are <strong>you</strong>";
echo htmlentitites($var);
```

Will encode it in the browser so you can see it displayed as plain text like in `$var`. The browser will see this:

> Hello&lt;br&gt;How are &lt;strong&gt;you&lt;/strong&gt;